# Erro de permissão do gitlab no visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, versionamento, gitlab

Estou com o erro abaixo quando tento fazer pull/push via visual studio.

```
Opening repositories:
C:\Projetos\Ecommerce\Epson
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.....com.br: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Git failed with a fatal error.
Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Quando faço pelo git bash funciona normalmente.
Sendo que estou usando uma SSL Key.

```
$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/marconcilioka/.ssh/id_rsa':
Already up to date.
```

Exite alguma configuração no visual studio para corrigir isso ?

Answer (score -1):

O Windows deve ter salvo suas credenciais git, que precisam ser atualizadas/removidas. As etapas abaixo funcionaram para mim no VS2017.

Vá para "Credential Manager" no Windows "Iniciar" e, em "Generic Credentials", selecione seu URL de git. Clique na seta do lado direito, ela deve ser expandida e você verá dois links "Editar" e "Remover do cofre".

Clique no último link (recomendável), reinicie o VS, abra seu projeto e faça uma solicitação de sincronização/recepção, ele deve solicitar que suas credenciais sejam inseridas e você deve estar pronto. obrigado